# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user') when using Supabase authentication in a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I'm developing a React application with Next.js and using Supabase for authentication. I have a custom hook called useAuthentication that checks if the user is logged in and redirects them to the login page if not. However, I'm encountering a runtime error stating "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')" in the useAuthentication.js file.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { auth } from '@supabase/supabase-js';
import { supabase } from '../supabase/supabaseConfig';

const useAuthentication = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkIfUserIsLoggedIn = async () => {
      const user = await auth.user();
      if (!user) {
        router.push('/login');
      }
    };

    checkIfUserIsLoggedIn();
  }, [router]);

  return null;
};

export default useAuthentication;
```

I have ensured that I properly initialized the supabase client in my supabaseConfig.js file and that the @supabase/supabase-js package is installed as a dependency.
this is my supabaseconfig file:

```
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";


const supabaseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASEURL
const supabaseKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASEKEY
export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey);
```

Could someone please help me understand why I'm getting this error and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: `auth` is undefined. Are you importing the file correctly?

Comment: yes these are my codes

Answer (score 0):

The import of `auth` is incorrect and there is no `user` method anymore as that was v1 of the supabase-js library, in v2 the method is `getUser`. You should be using the `supabase` you import in this file so it should be:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { supabase } from '../supabase/supabaseConfig';

const useAuthentication = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkIfUserIsLoggedIn = async () => {
    const user = await supabase.auth.getUser();
      if (!user) {
        router.push('/login');
      }
    };

    checkIfUserIsLoggedIn();
  }, [router]);

  return null;
};

export default useAuthentication;
```